# Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'Employee'

Tags: json, angular, typescript, foreach, observable

I'm returning and json object from a get request. I've tried to loop through it using forEach but get the error: Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'Employee'. Employee is an observable.

This is in Angular 7

```
employee: Employee[];

single: any = [
    {
      "name": [],
      "value": []
    }      
  ];
```

```
chartData(id){
    return this.employeeService.getEmpSkill(id)
      .subscribe( data => data.forEach((i) => {this.single.push({name: (i.skill_name), value: (i.score) })
      this.single = [...this.single]
      console.log(this.single)

    }));      
  }
```

[image]

I'm expecting an array to be returned so I can the data to a chart. Instead, I get: **error TS2339: Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'Employee'.**

Comment: your service seems to return `Observable<Employee>` not `Observable<Employee[]>`. You should check your types and apis to make sure you are interpreting the responses correctly.

Comment: Yes, that was it exactly. Thank you! As soon as I'm allowed I'll mark as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Answer submitted by @toskv
your service seems to return Observable not Observable. You should check your types and apis to make sure you are interpreting the responses correctly.